# How can I profile my Xamarin Forms application if I just have the free Mac OS version running

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

Seems like I need to upgrade to the professional version but are there any other ways that I can for example profile memory or thread usage in my application running on Mac OS?

Comment: App type: Android? iOS/macOS?

Comment: It's an iOS and Android Xamarin.Forms application.  I would like to be able to at least profile one or preferably both of them.

Comment: Maybe Android Studio and Xcode IDE can instead of  doing these.

Comment: I am pretty sure the below answer would work for your scenario

Answer (score 1):

For Android, you can use the Android Studio Profiler.

[Here is a detailed tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/profiling) how to set it up with Xamarin.Android applications.

As for iOS, if you have a Mac, you can use the Instruments App.

[Official Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/using-instruments-to-detect-native-leaks-using-markheap) shows you how to set it up.